# Defining the queue for an event in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have an event and a listener for the Event. So far, the listener is queueable, but it will always be set onto the "default" queue. In my case, I need this to be flexible, so that I can define the queue when the event is fired. I have not found anything to serve this purpose. What I'd like to do is something like the following.

```
event(testEvent::class, [['Some', 'thing']])->onQueue(80);
```

However, there is no `onQueue()` method for this. How do I set my event onto 'Queue X,' for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener should implement `ShouldQueue`. Because of this, it has a

```php
public $queue = 'listeners';
```

property and a

```php
public $connection = 'sqs';
```

property.

You can set these to customise the queue and connection the event listener will use.

An example of how you might use these properties at the point of firing the event is below.

```php
$event = new TestEvent();
$event->queue = 'other-queue';
event($event);
```

For further reference you can read the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#queued-event-listeners) section on this.

Comment: Thanks for that, i tried this, but my job is not on the queue i want to, the listener job stays on queue "default". Do i have to do anything with the event?

Comment: Does your listener implement ```ShouldQueue```?

Comment: Yes, ShouldQueue is implemented ... i even implemented it on the event for testing, but it does not work :(